# Is it possible to check the BIOS version of my computer on Ubuntu?

Tags: bios

Is it possible to check the BIOS version of my computer from a running Ubuntu instance?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the info from the computer's DMI (Desktop Management Interface) AKA SMBIOS (System Management BIOS) table, dump it using `dmidecode`, and get the value of type 0 (BIOS):

```
sudo dmidecode -t 0
sudo dmidecode -t 0 | grep 'Version:'

sudo dmidecode -t bios
sudo dmidecode -t bios | grep 'Version:'
```

Check `man dmidecode`.

**Example:**

```
% sudo dmidecode -t 0
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0x000f04c0
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: F14
    Release Date: 09/19/2014
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 8192 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 4.6

% sudo dmidecode -t 0 | grep 'Version:'
    Version: F14
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also examine the output of `lshw` to get some basic information about your BIOS:

```
$ sudo lshw | grep -A8 '*-firmware'
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Insyde Corp.
          physical id: 0
          version: V1.10
          date: 01/22/2016
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 8128KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
```